# How to generate the matrix [2,1,1,...,1,2] in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to generate a 1 x 50 matrix of the form

```
[2 1, 1, ..., 1, 2]
```

My thinking is:

```
ones(1,50)+[1,0.....,1]
```

but how to get the `[1,0.....,1]`? Do I need some for loop?

Comment: If you're feeling playful :-) ... `N=50; x = (mod(1:N,N)<2)+1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the indices `myArray(1)` and `myArray(end)` to change the first and last elements.

```
myArray = ones(1,50);
myArray(1) = 2; myArray(end) = 2;
```

If you know the array is always length 50, you can simply do

```
myArray = [2, ones(1,48), 2];
```

Comment: Or just `myArray([1,end]) = 2`.